# How to Retrieve record from MS-Access by order?

Tags: java, sql, database, ms-access

I am using `MS-Access` , i am just trying to retrieve the data from it.

It is fine, quiet working well,
now i need to retrieve the data from the `database` based upon **which data inserted first**.

**For Example**

[image]

In the above picture is my `MS-Access` database.

If i retrieve data and print it through `List` package normally it shows the output like the following figure

[image]

**The order is changed...**

How it is happening, i didn't use any `where` function and all...then why the order of rows is changed..while retrieving..!!

Any suggestion will be appreciated..

Comment: if you've got what you required from the answers given, mark the one as answer. or if you have gotten your own answer then post your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while saving data to a database it is not guaranteed that data is sorted in the order inserted. So on retrieving it there is no guarantee that it can be retrieved on the order inserted.

To achieve this, you can either have a sequential primary key or have a field with a time stamp.

While retrieving you can use either of the fields as a condition clause and an order by clause to retrieve rows in the desired order.

EDIT:
i believe the answer is already provided. to reiterate the answers

Solution 1:
Add a sequential primary key column to the table
while inserting the data, the column will increment itself by 1.
you can get the data by specifying the sequential primary key in the where clause.

Solution 2:
Add column of type Datetime to the table
while adding the data the timestamp of the insertion time will be inserted in the column (if you had written a trigger or getdate() as a default value)
while retrieving use the order by clause on the timestamp

Comment: Fine ...Are you sure that there is no guarantee in order of  data  as database have

Comment: you can use this [microsoft link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/save-a-sort-order-with-a-table-query-form-or-report-HA010222312.aspx#BM1)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to retrieve sorted data with the same output order a any time, is to use the `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: ya ..but `ORDER BY` is like  `assending` and `desending` based concept

Answer (score 1):

retrieval from database is not guaranteed to be in insertion order, to retrieve records in insertion order you might have to save the timestamp while inserting a record and order by the timestamp column while retrieving

Comment: Are you sure that we cannot retrieve the record as per by `insertion order`..Do you have any reference site relate to this conversation..

Comment: you might consider reading MS-ACCESS manuals but there is a chance that it wont state what the database does not do

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the `Id` column is automatically incremented, just add to the query used for retrieving data `ORDER BY Id ASC`.